# Splitting a tuple inline as parameters to a function with non-tuple arguments

Tags: f#

I've got a function that takes two parameters, for example:

```
let f a b = a = b
```

Then I have a second function that returns a tuple:

```
let g = (a, b)
```

I want to pass in a and b in the tuple from g as parameters to f in one line. I could do it in two statements, but the reason I want to do this is that my calling function does an or and I'd rather not call f unless the first case is false, to save on unnecessary processing.

```
let calling =
  someboolean || 
  f g // want to split result of g to parameters for f without calling g twice
```

Any tips on how to do this? I know I could have f take a tuple instead, but I'd like to retain the option for currying.

I hope I explained this well enough. :)

Comment: [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) a nice, organized reference list of F# symbols and operators, if you need more info about the other answers

Comment: I would have marked several answers if I could, but I picked what I thought was the most elegant solution to the particular question. That said, I think Thomas's suggestion about refactoring the the f and g calls is probably the most "correct". Thanks all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also do:

```
let calling = someBoolean || g ||> f
```

Because:

```
(||>) : ('a * 'b -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'c)
```

(And similarly `(|||>) : ('a * 'b * 'c -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> 'd)`)

Comment: There're also `(<||)` and `(<|||)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a function which converts a curried function into one which takes a pair argument:

```
uncurry f (a, b) = f a b

let calling = someBoolean || (uncurry f) g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract from the tuple inline, you'll still get the benefit of the short-circuiting.

```
let calling = someBoolean || let a,b = g in f a b
```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you could define the `uncurry` combinator to convert function taking two arguments into a function taking tuple.

However I'd recommend not doing that - that style of programming is not really idiomatic in F# (unlike, say, in Haskell) and I think it makes code hard to read, debug and maintain.

So, what to do instead?

- If the two values logically belong together (represent some entity used elsewhere in your code) then change `f` to take a tuple too.
- If they are just two values, then use `let` and pattern matching to decompose the tuple. This will be longer, but you'll have to name the components, which will improve readability.

In your sample `g` is actually a value so you can write just:

```
let someThing, otherThing = g
boolThing || (f someThing otherThing)
```

Comment: I thinkt that's the best answer @TomasPetricek. Decomposing the tuple into two values is probably easiest to read and also feels most "right" in terms of F# idiom.

Comment: Yeah, my main reason for not doing this was to keep the short circuiting of the 'or'. In the actual code, there's some enumeration and potential database access in g, so I didn't want to hit that code if the first part of the conditional evaluated to true.

Comment: @McMuttons sounds like you want to use F#'s brilliant `Lazy<_>` type, with `lazy ...` expressions.

Comment: @McMuttons Yes, I think getting short-circuiting is a very good reason for asking this question. My recommendation would be to refactor the right branch into a separate function and then just call that (for readability, plus, you can just use nested function in F#!)